# Transform a direction from world space to local space?

Tags: vectors, 3d, transformation

I've been reading [this pdf](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-07-dynamics-fall-2009/lecture-notes/MIT16_07F09_Lec03.pdf) about vector transformations and I don't quite understand how to implement it in a computer program. On page 10, it shows you how to transform a vector from one coordinate system to another, exactly how would this look on paper? Say I had two 3d vectors that represented directions and I wanted to get the relative direction of $vector A$ to $vector B$. So if $A = (0,0,0)$ and $B = (0,1,0)$, $C$ would also be $(0,1,0)$. If $A = (0,1,0)$, $C$ would then be $(0,0,-1)$. Would I make matrices of $A$ and $B$ and just multiply them together? Other places have talked about getting the dot product? What would the $i$ and $i'$ vectors be in this case? Thank you.

I'm pretty sure this is all the info I need but in case there is an obviously better way of doing it I will explain my project. It's a simple voxel 3D raycaster. I'm actually using Unity and rendering to a texture using a compute shader.

The way I am calculating the rays is I am centering the pixel coordinates as if they were 3D space coordinates, moving them a little forward and getting the directions from 0,0,0 to each of those points (and shrinking the dimensions for field-of-view). Then, I transform those directions relative to the player's transform every frame to get the ray directions for the GPU. Obviously, this also needs to be calculated on the GPU so I can't use the handy Unity method I used just to test if it would work (Transform.TransformDirection). So I guess I could also use a relative point transform function too and just send those points and the player's transform to the GPU.

Comment: Are you building a rasterizer or a raytracer ? Generally, you'd use a $4 \times 4$ homogeneous matrix (encoding scaling, rotations, and translations) for the position vector of your ray, and a $3 \times 3$ matrix (encoding scaling and rotations) for the direction vector of your ray. If I have your context, I might be able to guide you better.

Comment: It's a raytracer, why does the transform of the ray matter? I just need the world space direction of one direction relative to another and then I can take the given point and raycast from there, right? I'll edit and explain more :)

Comment: Well it depends on how you bounce your rays, basically. If you do everything in world space; you don't need anything else, but expressing ellipsoids (or any other fundamental primitive scaled or rotated or positioned freely for each axis) and their normals can be pretty hard. On the other hand, using an object space requires the ray's position, its direction, and the normal to the primitive at the hitpoint, to all be fed to different matrices for things to work properly. Do you want me to give you a full picture of how to handle a graphics pipeline ?

Comment: I appreciate it but I don't think that will be necessary, read my edits. I am using cubic voxels so calculating the normals will be easy and I will probably use DDA for the rayscasting (I am using an even simpler method now just for testing) I haven't even really begun to think about bouncing

Comment: For a practical thing: have you tried just looking up the actual implementations behind those handy Unity functions?

Comment: Indeed, if your only objects are voxels, then I suggest forgoing the object space altogether, and considering each voxel a section of an axis-aligned bounding box (AABB) since these are much, much, much faster (and you should add an acceleration structure to boot). However, I find the fact that you haven't considered bouncing worrying, especially if you want to use the GPU. What algorithm do you plan on using for your rays to reach the various light sources and contribute color to each pixel ?

Comment: @TristanDuquesne well all I have really thought about is that there will be a light source/s and I would cast another ray from the hit point to the light source/s? And maybe store the total lightness of each voxel and have each voxel in view look at its neighbors for ambient lighting. The empty voxels could store lighting data as well.

Comment: @user3482749 no lol I'm looking right now I feel like I have tried to find stuff like this before and I couldn't find it. The method I need is Transform.TransformDirection()

Comment: If you have multiple light sources, you need to split the ray that hits a given object into multiple secondary rays to query each light source (and see both if the point is in a shadow for that light source; or alternatively the angle, color, intensity etc contribution of that light source to that point). The complexity is compounded if you consider other objects as secondary light sources. This branching "if-else-stop" tree structure for your bouncing is precisely what you DON'T want on a GPU. This is why, when using a GPU, we prefer path-tracing (probabilistic) algorithms like MCPT and BDPT.

Comment: @Tristan367 If you're struggling to find it, writing a short programme which calls it and throws an error will give you a link straight to it in either of the default Unity editors.

Comment: @user3482749 I don't know what you mean. All I see is a link to the line in my code when I create an error. And it is very specific to the error itself. Why would that link to the source code for their Transform class? I thought you needed a license to see Unity source code?

Comment: I think I am starting to get the equation in the pdf, you have to get the forward, right, and up directions in world space. How do you do that? Say if I had a forward direction of (1,1,1), how do you calculate the up and right of that?

Comment: @Tristan367 Oh yeah, sorry, it's been a while since I used a non-license version, and the link is there if you're on a licensed version. For the last question: you can't. That isn't enough information (you also need the rotation around that axis).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So [this page](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/8562/how-to-convert-from-object-space-into-world-space-exercise-from-3d-math-primer) ended up helping me. I simply send the positions of the pixels as if they were a screen slightly in front of the player at 0,0,0 and center them and whatnot, then in the compute shader I transform those points to world space relative to the player's rotation for each ray like this:

```
float3 transformDirectionFromPoint(float3 p) {

  float3 u1 = p.x * playerWorldRight;
  float3 u2 = p.y * playerWorldUp;
  float3 u3 = p.z * playerWorldForward;

  return u1 + u2 + u3; // the direction to that point
}
```

And then I use that direction to cast a ray out from the player's position. I found with higher resolutions I needed to decrease the field of view.

Answer (score 3):

Voxel tracing differs from ordinary ray tracing in that you want to use a coordinate system where the voxels are defined for each unit cell, i.e. for unit (integer) coordinates.

You can use one vector, say $\vec{o}$ for observer (eye) location (in the voxel coordinates), and an unit quaternion $\mathbf{q} = q_r + q_x \mathbf{i} + q_y \mathbf{j} + q_z \mathbf{k} = (q_x, q_y, q_z; q_r)$ to describe the observer orientation; it corresponds to rotation matrix $\mathbf{R}$ via
$$\mathbf{R} = \left[ \begin{matrix}
1-2( q_y^2 + q_z^2 ) & 2( q_x q_y- q_z q_r) & 2( q_x q_z+ q_y q_r) \\
2( q_x q_y+ q_z q_r) & 1-2( q_x^2 + q_z^2 ) & 2( q_y q_z- q_x q_r) \\
2( q_x q_z- q_y q_r) & 2( q_y q_z+ q_x q_r) & 1-2( q_x^2 + q_y^2 ) \\
\end{matrix} \right] = \left[ \begin{matrix}
u_x & v_x & w_x \\ u_y & v_y & w_y \\ u_z & v_z & w_z \\
\end{matrix} \right] = \left[ \begin{matrix} \hat{u} & \hat{v} & \hat{w} \end{matrix} \right]$$
where $\hat{w}$ is the "forward" unit vector in voxel coordinates, $\hat{v}$ is "up", and $\hat{u}$ is "right".  For the identity unit quaternion $\mathbf{q} = 1 = (0, 0, 0; 1)$, $\hat{u} = (1, 0, 0)$, $\hat{v} = (0, 1, 0)$, and $\hat{w} = (0, 0, 1)$.

The reason for using a quaternion (or a bivector, which yields the same math) is that the orientation can be safely normalized by dividing each of the four components by $\sqrt{q_r^2 + q_x^2 + q_y^2 + q_z^2}$, because for unit quaternions, $q_r^2 + q_x^2 + q_y^2 + q_z^2 = 1$.  To apply a rotation $\mathbf{t}$ to the orientation, you use Hamilton product:
$$\left\lbrace\begin{aligned}
q_r^\prime &= t_r q_r - t_x q_x - t_y q_y - t_z q_z \\
q_x^\prime &= t_r q_x + t_x q_r + t_y q_z - t_z q_y \\
q_y^\prime &= t_r q_y - t_x q_z + t_y q_r + t_z q_x \\
q_z^\prime &= t_r q_z + t_x q_y - t_y q_x + t_z q_r \\
\end{aligned} \right.$$
If the projection plane (view in voxel coordinates) is $2 \chi$ wide and $2 \gamma$ tall, at distance $d$ from the observer, each ray $(i, j)$ ($0 \le i \le i_\max$, $0 \le j \le j_\max$) has unnormalized ray direction vector $\vec{s}$,
$$\vec{s} = d \hat{w} + \left(\frac{i}{i_\max} - \frac{1}{2}\right) \chi \hat{u} + \left(\frac{j}{j_\max} - \frac{1}{2}\right) \gamma \hat{v}$$
and starts at $\vec{p}$,
$$\vec{p} = \vec{o} + \vec{s}$$
The interesting thing is that if you calculate the unit ray vector $\hat{r}$,
$$\hat{r} = \frac{\vec{s}}{\lVert\vec{s}\rVert} = \left[\begin{matrix} r_x \\ r_y \\ r_z \end{matrix} \right]$$
its reciprocal components tell you the interval at which the ray steps one voxel unit along each axis,
$$\left\lbrace \begin{aligned}
L_x &= \frac{1}{\lvert r_x \rvert}, \\
L_y &= \frac{1}{\lvert r_y \rvert}, \\
L_z &= \frac{1}{\lvert r_z \rvert}, \\
\end{aligned} \right. \quad \begin{aligned}
S_x &= \operatorname{sign}(r_x) = \frac{r_x}{\lvert r_x \rvert} \\
S_y &= \operatorname{sign}(r_y) = \frac{r_y}{\lvert r_y \rvert} \\
S_z &= \operatorname{sign}(r_z) = \frac{r_z}{\lvert r_z \rvert} \\
\end{aligned}$$
where $S_x$, $S_y$, $S_z$ are $-1$, $0$, or $+1$ depending on the direction of the ray, and division by zero yields either $\infty$ or a value larger than the voxel map size.

The initial distance $d_x$ where the ray intersects a voxel $x$ face, is
$$d_x = \begin{cases}
( p_x - \lfloor p_x \rfloor ) L_x, & S_x = -1 \\
\infty, & S_x = 0 \\
( \lceil p_x \rceil - p_x ) L_x, & S_x = +1 \\
\end{cases}$$
$d_x \ge 0$; and similarly for the $y$ and $z$ axes.

Instead of progressing the ray at fixed length steps, you examine where the ray next intersects a voxel face.  You do this by choosing the smallest of $d_x$, $d_y$, and $d_z$.

If $d_x$ is the smallest of the three, the ray length $d$ is set to $d_x$, then $d_x$ increased by $L_x$ (corresponding to the distance where the ray intersects the next $x$ face), and the ray intersects a voxel $x$ face at $\vec{p} + d \hat{r}$.  Similarly for the other two coordinates.

You may need to handle the rare cases $d_x = d_y$, $d_x = d_z$, etc. where the ray intersects a voxel edge, and $d_x = d_y = d_z$ where the ray intersects a voxel vertex, separately.

The voxel is identified by the integer part of coordinates of $\vec{p} + d \hat{r}$.  The fractional parts correspond to the fractional coordinates within the voxel, remembering that the above method only examines voxel *faces*; at least one of the coordinates is always an integer.  This allows you to use textures for each voxel face, if you want.

---

Consider the following 2D scenario for a single ray starting at lower left, progressing up right:
[image: 2D lattice wall intersections]
The distance along the ray between the blue tabs is $L_x$, and between the red tabs is $L_y$. We walk in increasing distance.

If we call vertical/blue faces $x$ (because they occur at integer $x$ coordinates), and horizontal/red faces $y$, the order in which the ray encounters these faces is $x$, $y$, $x$, $y$, $x$, $x$, $y$, $x$, $x$, $y$, $x$, $y$, $x$, $x$, $y$, and so on.

---

Nothing beats an example, I guess.  Here is a horrible-crude-simple tracer in Python 3:

```
# SPDX-License-Identifier: CC0-1.0
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from math import inf as _inf, sqrt as _sqrt, copysign as _copysign, floor as _floor

class Vector(tuple):
    """Immutable, compact 3D vector"""

    def __new__(cls, *args):
        """Create a new 3D vector

           Usage:
             v = Vector(x, y, z)
             v = Vector((x, y, z))
             v = Vector([x, y, z])
             v = Vector(v)
        """
        if len(args) == 1:
            if isinstance(args[0], (tuple, list)):
                args = args[0]
            else:
                raise TypeError("Cannot construct a Vector from a %s." % str(type(args[0])))
        if len(args) != 3:
            raise ValueError("Vector() needs three components; %d given." % len(args))

        return tuple.__new__(cls, (float(args[0]), float(args[1]), float(args[2])))

    def __init__(self, *args):
        """Vectors are immutable"""
        pass

    def __str__(self):
        return "(%.6f, %.6f, %.6f)" % self

    @property
    def x(self):
        """X coordinate"""
        return self[0]

    @property
    def y(self):
        """Y coordinate"""
        return self[1]

    @property
    def z(self):
        """Z coordinate"""
        return self[2]

    @property
    def normsqr(self):
        """Squared norm, i.e. Euclidean length squared"""
        return self[0]*self[0] + self[1]*self[1] + self[2]*self[2]

    @property
    def length(self):
        """Euclidean length"""
        return _sqrt(self[0]*self[0] + self[1]*self[1] + self[2]*self[2])

    @property
    def normalized(self):
        """Vector normalized to unit length"""
        n = _sqrt(self[0]*self[0] + self[1]*self[1] + self[2]*self[2])
        if n == 1:
            return self
        elif n > 0:
            return tuple.__new__(self.__class__, (self[0]/n, self[1]/n, self[2]/n))
        else:
            raise ValueError("Cannot normalize a zero vector to unit length!")

    def dot(self, other):
        """Vector dot product"""
        if not isinstance(other, Vector):
            other = Vector(other)
        return self[0]*other[0] + self[1]*other[1] + self[2]*other[2]

    def cross(self, other):
        """Vector cross product"""
        if not isinstance(other, Vector):
            other = Vector(other)
        return tuple.__new__(self.__class__, ( self[1]*other[2] - self[2]*other[1],
                                               self[2]*other[0] - self[0]*other[2],
                                               self[0]*other[1] - self[1]*other[0] ))

    def proj(self, other):
        """Vector projection to another vector"""
        if not isinstance(other, Vector):
            other = Vector(other)
        n = ( self[0]*other[0] +
              self[1]*other[1] +
              self[2]*other[2] ) / ( other[0]*other[0] +
                                     other[1]*other[1] +
                                     other[2]*other[2] )
        return tuple.__new__(self.__class__, ( n*other[0], n*other[1], n*other[2] ))

    def perp(self, other):
        """The part of current vector perpendicular to the other vector"""
        unit = Vector(other).normalized
        return self - unit*self.dot(unit)

    def __add__(self, other):
        """Vector addition"""
        if isinstance(other, (tuple, list)) and len(other) == 3:
            return tuple.__new__(self.__class__, ( self[0] + float(other[0]),
                                                   self[1] + float(other[1]),
                                                   self[2] + float(other[2]) ))
        else:
            return NotImplemented

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        """Vector addition"""
        if isinstance(other, (tuple, list)) and len(other) == 3:
            return tuple.__new__(self.__class__, ( self[0] + float(other[0]),
                                                   self[1] + float(other[1]),
                                                   self[2] + float(other[2]) ))
        else:
            return NotImplemented

    def __radd__(self, other):
        """Vector addition"""
        if isinstance(other, (tuple, list)) and len(other) == 3:
            return tuple.__new__(self.__class__, ( float(other[0]) + self[0],
                                                   float(other[1]) + self[1],
                                                   float(other[2]) + self[2] ))
        else:
            return NotImplemented

    def __sub__(self, other):
        """Vector subtraction"""
        if isinstance(other, (tuple, list)) and len(other) == 3:
            return tuple.__new__(self.__class__, ( self[0] - float(other[0]),
                                                   self[1] - float(other[1]),
                                                   self[2] - float(other[2]) ))
        else:
            return NotImplemented

    def __isub__(self, other):
        """Vector subtraction"""
        if isinstance(other, (tuple, list)) and len(other) == 3:
            return tuple.__new__(self.__class__, ( self[0] - float(other[0]),
                                                   self[1] - float(other[1]),
                                                   self[2] - float(other[2]) ))
        else:
            return NotImplemented

    def __rsub__(self, other):
        """Vector subtraction"""
        if isinstance(other, (tuple, list)) and len(other) == 3:
            return tuple.__new__(self.__class__, ( float(other[0]) - self[0],
                                                   float(other[1]) - self[1],
                                                   float(other[2]) - self[2] ))
        else:
            return NotImplemented

    def __mul__(self, other):
        """Vector-scalar multiplication"""
        if isinstance(other, (int, float)):
            return tuple.__new__(self.__class__, ( self[0]*other,
                                                   self[1]*other,
                                                   self[2]*other ))
        else:
            return NotImplemented

    def __imul__(self, other):
        """Vector-scalar multiplication"""
        if isinstance(other, (int, float)):
            return tuple.__new__(self.__class__, ( self[0]*other,
                                                   self[1]*other,
                                                   self[2]*other ))
        else:
            return NotImplemented

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        """Scalar-vector multiplication"""
        if isinstance(other, (int, float)):
            return tuple.__new__(self.__class__, ( other*self[0],
                                                   other*self[1],
                                                   other*self[2] ))
        else:
            return NotImplemented

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        """Vector-scalar division"""
        if isinstance(other, (int, float)):
            return tuple.__new__(self.__class__, ( self[0]/other,
                                                   self[1]/other,
                                                   self[2]/other ))
        else:
            return NotImplemented

    def __itruediv__(self, other):
        """Vector-scalar division"""
        if isinstance(other, (int, float)):
            return tuple.__new__(self.__class__, ( self[0]/other,
                                                   self[1]/other,
                                                   self[2]/other ))
        else:
            return NotImplemented

    def __rtruediv__(self, other):
        """Division by vector not implemented"""
        return NotImplemented

    def __neg__(self):
        """Unary - (Vector negation)"""
        return tuple.__new__(self.__class__, ( -self[0], -self[1], -self[2] ))

    def __pos__(self):
        """Unary + (No effect)"""
        return self

    def __abs__(self):
        """abs() (Euclidean length)"""
        return _sqrt(self[0]*self[0] + self[1]*self[1] + self[2]*self[2])

    def __invert__(self):
        """Unary ~ (Vector scaled to reciprocal length)"""
        n = self[0]*self[0] + self[1]*self[1] + self[2]*self[2]
        return tuple.__new__(self.__class__, ( self[0]/n, self[1]/n, self[2]/n ))

    def __bool__(self):
        """Zero vectors are False, nonzero vectors True"""
        return (self[0]*self[0] + self[1]*self[1] + self[2]*self[2]) > 0.0

def _step_start_length(direction, start):
    one = abs(direction)

    try:
        len_x = one / abs(direction.x)
        sgn_x = int(_copysign(1.0, direction.x))
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        len_x = _inf
        sgn_x = 0

    try:
        len_y = one / abs(direction.y)
        sgn_y = int(_copysign(1.0, direction.y))
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        len_y = _inf
        sgn_y = 0

    try:
        len_z = one / abs(direction.z)
        sgn_z = int(_copysign(1.0, direction.z))
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        len_z = _inf
        sgn_z = 0

    if sgn_x > 0:
        dist_x = (_floor(start.x + 1) - start.x) * len_x
    elif sgn_x < 0:
        dist_x = (start.x - _floor(start.x)) * len_x
    else:
        dist_x = len_x

    if sgn_y > 0:
        dist_y = (_floor(start.y + 1) - start.y) * len_y
    elif sgn_y < 0:
        dist_y = (start.y - _floor(start.y)) * len_y
    else:
        dist_y = len_y

    if sgn_z > 0:
        dist_z = (_floor(start.z + 1) - start.z) * len_z
    elif sgn_z < 0:
        dist_z = (start.z - _floor(start.z)) * len_z
    else:
        dist_z = len_z

    return (sgn_x, sgn_y, sgn_z), Vector(dist_x, dist_y, dist_z), Vector(len_x, len_y, len_z)


class View:
    """2D view into a voxel lattice"""

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self._voxel = None
        self._position = Vector(0, 0, -50)
        self._basis = (Vector(1,0,0), Vector(0,1,0), Vector(0,0,1))
        self._picture_distance = 10
        self._picture_halfsize = 8
        self._xsize = 320
        self._ysize = 160
        self._colors = [ b'\x00\x00\x00',   # Background #000000
                         b'\x33\x99\xff',   #    X faces #3399ff
                         b'\x33\xff\x99',   #    Y faces #33ff99
                         b'\x33\xcc\xcc',   #   XY edges #33cccc
                         b'\xff\x99\x33',   #    Z faces #ff9933
                         b'\xcc\x66\xcc',   #   XZ edges #cc66cc
                         b'\xcc\xcc\x66',   #   YZ edges #cccc66
                         b'\xcc\xcc\xcc',   #  XYZ vertx #cccccc
                       ]

    def renderPPM(self, output, voxel):
        output.write(b'P6\n%d %d 255\n' % (self._xsize, self._ysize))
        picx = (self._picture_halfsize / self._xsize) * self._basis[0]
        picy = (-self._picture_halfsize / self._xsize) * self._basis[1]
        pic0 = self._position + self._picture_distance * self._basis[2] - picx * (0.5 * self._xsize) - picy * (0.5 * self._ysize)

        for y in range(0, self._ysize):
            for x in range(0, self._xsize):
                start = pic0 + x*picx + y*picy
                delta = (start - self._position).normalized
                step, nextdist, length = _step_start_length(delta, start)
                dist = 0

                while True:

                    # Blank wall at distance 200
                    if dist >= 200:
                        face = 0
                        break

                    elif nextdist.x < nextdist.y and nextdist.x < nextdist.z:
                        dist = nextdist.x
                        nextdist += (length.x, 0, 0)
                        face = 1

                    elif nextdist.y < nextdist.x and nextdist.y < nextdist.z:
                        dist = nextdist.y
                        nextdist += (0, length.y, 0)
                        face = 2

                    elif nextdist.z < nextdist.x and nextdist.z < nextdist.y:
                        dist = nextdist.z
                        nextdist += (0, 0, length.z)
                        face = 4

                    elif nextdist.x == nextdist.y and nextdist.x < nextdist.z:
                        dist = nextdist.x
                        nextdist += (length.x, length.y, 0)
                        face = 1 + 2

                    elif nextdist.x == nextdist.z and nextdist.x < nextdist.y:
                        dist = nextdist.x
                        nextdist += (length.x, 0, length.z)
                        face = 1 + 4

                    elif nextdist.y == nextdist.z and nextdist.y < nextdist.x:
                        dist = nextdist.y
                        nextdist += (0, length.y, length.z)
                        face = 2 + 4

                    else:
                        dist = nextdist.x
                        nextdist += (length.x, length.y, length.z)
                        face = 1 + 2 + 4

                    if voxel(start + dist * delta, face):
                        break

                output.write(self._colors[face])

            print("Row %d of %d rendered" % (y + 1, self._ysize))


def voxel(point, face):

    # Voxel map has a spheroid-thingy of radius 6 at (10,4,3)
    if (point - (10,4,3)).normsqr <= 36:
        return True

    # and a bigger one at (-20,0,10)
    if (point - (-20,0,10)).normsqr <= 144:
        return True

    return False


if __name__ == '__main__':

    view = View()

    with open('out.ppm', 'wb') as out:
        view.renderPPM(out, voxel)

    print("Saved 'out.ppm'.")
```

Near the end, the `voxel()` function determines what is visible.  It saves a NetPBM P6 image (Portable Pixmap format) `out.ppm`, which looks like:
[image: out.ppm]

Comment: Thank you, I had learned about a 2D version of this called DDA and was planning on figuring it out soon! Where you calculate r, what is r? Do the double bars around a vector mean it is normalized? And then do I just divide r.x by 1 to get the movement on the x-axis, for instance?

Comment: @Tristan367: You get $\vec{r}$ by normalizing $\vec{s}$ to unit length.  Yes, $\lVert \vec{s} \rVert = \sqrt{\vec{s} \cdot \vec{s}}$ is the Euclidean length of vector $\vec{s}$.  The idea is that $d_x$, $d_y$, and $d_z$ describe the *distance* (from the ray starting point) where the ray intersects the next voxel $x$, $y$, or $z$ face, respectively.  Instead of walking in fixed ray length steps, you keep track of the distance at which the ray intersects the next face (of the three possible types), and *jump* to the nearest distance.  Perhaps I should draw a 2D diagram to describe the idea?

Comment: That may be helpful thank you. So "unit length" is 1 in this case, right? I can just use the normalize() function available to me. And I'm still lost on some of the notation, sorry this is my fault for going to a math forum lol what does $⌊$ and $⌈$ mean? And when you put stuff in curly brackets does that mean those are different cases? And is the comma denoting a different option for that case? Such as where you calculate $dx$? Say I had a direction $d = (1,1,1)$ and a point $p = (0,0.5,0)$, how would I find $dx$, $dy$, and $dz$?

Comment: @Tristan367: Yes, unit length is always $1$. $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is `floor(x)`, $\lfloor x \rceil$ is `round(x)`, and $\lceil x \rceil$ is `ceil(x)`.  If your ray direction (length irrelevant) is $\vec{s} = (1, 1, 1)$, then normalized to unit length the ray is $\hat{r} = (\sqrt{1/3}, \sqrt{1/3}, \sqrt{1/3})$, and therefore $L_x=L_y=L_z=\sqrt{3}$.  Let's say $\vec{p} = (0, 0.1, 0.6)$. We have $d_x = L_x$ (since $p_x$ is integer); $d_y = 0.9 L_y$; and $d_z = 0.4 L_z$.  So, first face is $z$ (at distance $d_z$), then $y$ (at distance $d_y$), then $x$ (at distance $d_x$), then $z$ again.

Comment: Ok I tried implementing it and I can get the distances to either the ceiled or floored version of the coordinate depending on the direction. And then I simply multiply the normalized direction of the ray by the smallest distance and add it to a vector holding the current point. But I just get a black screen. That should work, right?

Comment: If I add this $if (increment < 0.1) increment = 0.1$ I get slightly fuzzy cubes. Meaning I think it is kinda working. So it's like my increment becomes too small or something.

Comment: I started a new post about this so you could see my code :) https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/191245/dda-voxel-raycasting-algorithm-not-working-correctly

Comment: @Tristan367: I recommend you look at the Python voxel raycaster I added to the answer.  It is very simple, the raycaster itself is just a couple of dozen lines, but of course slow.  And it's horribly ugly, but I just wanted to let everybody interested see (and use – it's Creative Commons Zero -licensed –) as I am probably explaining the details quite badly.  Note that the distances I use are $1/r_x$, $1/r_y$, $1/r_z$; and I use `inf` (could also use just a big number) if the division would cause a division by zero.

Comment: I kind of got it working in my project but there are still problems could you check out the link I gave? Don't worry it's actually much less lines of code than your example lol but I appreciate it I am looking at it now.

Comment: I included a couple pictures of the error and what it looks like marching the ray by one unit in the link too.