# Know if a point and a vector pass through area

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, 3d

I want to make a concept that can be linked with ray-tracing, here applied to Minecraft.

It it's a 3D world, so there is X/Y/Z, with decimal value.

I have 2 vectors:

1. The begin position
2. Direction of line which is between -1 and 1 (so for example 0.5/-0.3/0.5).

In this 3D world, there is a block which have a size of 1 (1x, 1y, 1z).

I have to see what is the next block in the vector direction, limited to 10 blocks.

I tried something like that:

1. Divide the vector to make more iteration (i.e. 0.5/0.2/0.5 become 0.25/0.1/0.25)
2. Add the vector to the location to "walk" to the next point

Here is an example where red point at all point and green line are blocks.
[image]

The issue here is that the yellow block isn't count. Such as the next point is too far (and the last was not enough) it pass through but don't detect it.

I tried to divide the vector but I will always have false positive, and it also take more time...

How can I do ?

Comment: You are not totally clear, but if I understand you correctly - your line goes through planes and you just need to calculate the intersection of your vector (line) with the plans as it goes through - and this will provide you with (entering block) then you determine the exit point by calculating if the intersection point with the next level and by the grid values you can calculate how many blocks are intersected for that level.

Comment: If I well understand what you said, yes. I know how to do that in 2D context but not in 3D

Comment: There is a simple possible algorithms that could easily provide the desired result which requires solving, relatively simple several systems of 3 unknown equations. Interested?

Comment: Idk, maybe yes because I post this question ?

Comment: Are you stratified with the answer you got?

Comment: Do you know how to get the two planes equation which intersection contain the ray?

Comment: Just set values in the "direction" as integers for one of the values and calculate intersection points at such surface by just adding the appropriate values to the other axis values.

Comment: Sound like you just need to "scan convert" (or rasterize) the line into the grid. You can use any line algorithm, like DDA, extend it to 3D and use it to walk all the cells that the line crosses.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_differential_analyzer_(graphics_algorithm)

Answer (score 2):

This is a basic raycasting algorithm that tracks the ray intersections with *integer coordinates along each axis*, i.e. its intersections with the $yz$ plane at each integer $x$ coordinate, intersections with the $xz$ plane at each integer $y$ coordinate, and intersections with the $xy$ plane at each integer $z$ coordinate, along the ray.

Start with the ray starting position vector $\vec{s} = (s_x, s_y, s_z)$ and the ray unit direction vector $\hat{d} = (d_x, d_y, d_z)$, $\lVert\hat{d}\rVert = \sqrt{d_x^2 + d_y^2 + d_z^2} = 1$.

Using a vector-valued function, points $\vec{p}$ along the ray using distance parameter $t$, $t \ge 0$, are $\vec{p}(t) = \vec{s} + t \hat{d}$.  This means we only really need to know the distances $t$ for the abovementioned intersections, in the order they occur starting at $t = 0$ –– and this is obviously in order of increasing $t$.

If we measure the distance between consecutive intersections with the $yz$ plane along the direction vector, we'll find it is exactly $1/d_x$; and similarly $1/d_y$ for $x_z$ plane, and $1/d_z$ for the $y_z$ plane.

Initial values of $t$ for each coordinate axis –– let's call them $t_x$, $t_y$, and $t_z$ –– depend on the fractional part of the starting position coordinates.  Because the fractional part describes directly how much of the inter-integer-coordinate distance is left to the next smaller integer coordinate value, calculating the initial distances is trivial:

- If starting position coordinate is an integer, then the corresponding $t$ is either zero or the full inter-integer-coordinate distance along that axis.  It is up to you, whether you wish to consider the plane that would intersect the eye or lens of the observer, or only the following ones.
- If starting position coordinate is not an integer, and the corresponding direction vector component is negative, then the corresponding $t$ is the fractional part of the starting position coordinate divided by the (absolute value, or negated) direction vector component.
- If starting position coordinate is not an integer, and the corresponding direction vector component is positive, then the corresponding $t$ is the fractional part of the starting position coordinate subtracted from 1 (to get the fractional distance to the next higher integer), divided by the corresponding direction vector component.

When the above are known, we start with the smallest known $t$, check that intersection, and add the distance to the next intersection along that particular axis to that value for the next comparison, and repeat until we exceed the visible distance.

---

Let's say $\vec{s} = (1.0, 4.5, 2.3)$ and $\hat{d} = (2/7, -3/7, 6/7)$.

The integer distances along each axis are then $T_x = 7/2 = 3.5$, $T_y = 7/3 \approx 2.333$, and $T_z = 7/6 \approx 1.667$.

Because $s_x$ is an integer, $t_x = 0$ or $t_x = 7/2 = 3.5$; I pick the latter, because I don't think I'd see a plane intersecting my eye.

Because fractional part of $s_y = 0.5$ and $d_y \lt 0$, $t_y = 0.5 T_y = 7/6 \approx 1.667$.

Because fractional part of $s_z = 0.3$ and $d_z \gt 0$, $t_z = (1-0.3) T_z = 0.7 T_z = 49/60 \approx 0.817$.

Initial cell (integer) coordinates are obtained by rounding down the starting point coordinates, so $(1,4,2)$.  (If you use unsigned integer coordinates, then you can truncate; otherwise you need to use `floor()`, and `c - floor(c)` to get the fractional part.  The convention is that each cubic cell is identified by the smallest integer coordinates of its vertices.)

Note that if you consider cells "boxes", each integer coordinate plane belongs to *two* "boxes".  If you forget this, you'll see "boxes" that only have three sides, instead of six.

So, the raycasting loop starts with $t_x = 3.5$, $t_y \approx 1.667$, and $t_z \approx 0.817$, with $T_x = 3.5$, $T_y \approx 2.333$, and $T_z \approx 1.667$, in cell $(1, 4, 2)$.

Since $t_z$ is the smallest, the first possible intersection occurs at $t = t_z \approx 0.817$, at the upper $z$ wall (because $d_z \gt 0$) of cell $(1, 4, 2)$, entering cell $(1, 4, 3)$.  $t_z$ will be incremented by $T_z$, to $t_z \approx 1.983$.

Since $t_y$ is now smallest, the next possible intersection occurs at $t = t_y \approx 1.667$, at the lower $y$ wall (because $d_y \lt 0$) of cell $(1, 4, 3)$, entering cell $(1, 3, 3)$.  $t_y$ will be incremented by $T_y$, to $t_y = 3.5$.

Since $t_z$ is again smallest, the next possible intersection occurs at $t = t_z \approx 1.983$, at the upper $z$ wall of cell $(1,3,3)$, entering cell $(1,3,4)$.  $t_z$ is incremented by $T_z$, to $3.150$.

$t_z$ is again smallest, so the next possible intersection occurs at $t = t_z \approx 3.150$, at the upper $z$ wall of cell $(1,3,4)$, entering cell $(1,3,5)$.  $t_z$ is incremented by $T_z$, to $4.317$.

Next, $t_x$ and $t_y$ are the smallest, so the next possible intersection occurs at $t = t_x = t_y = 3.5$, at the edge where upper $x$ wall (because $d_x \gt 0$) and lower $y$ wall (because $d_y \lt 0$) of cell $(1, 3, 5)$, entering cell $(2, 2, 5)$.  $t_x$ is incremented by $T_x$, becoming $7$, and $t_y$ by $T_y$, becoming $5.833$.

This is repeated until $t$ exceeds the visible distance.  Note that $t$ is also the distance between the observer and the surface the ray hits, so you can add distance-dependent haze/blending very easily.

There are many programmatic tricks to make the inner loop as fast as possible (for example, you *could* do all 26 direction variants), but that's obviously a separate matter.

Mathematically, one could track a pair or quad of rays (spanning an area of the display), and split them (doubling the number of rays if still visually useful) whenever they diverge enough (not in the same or neighboring cells), to avoid recomputing the same ray path repeatedly.  This, however, is a raycasting algorith optimization, and again not math, and therefore unsuitable to elaborate in this answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will check it tomorrow (and accept it tomorrow too, after real feedback)

Comment: Sounds a little complicated - what is the purpose? Identify if a block pierced by the ray or  the sequence of pierced blocks?

Comment: @Moti: The idea is raycasting in a world where each integer coordinate cell is either empty, or contains a cube.  To be useful for us humans, the visible distance must be at least a couple of dozen cubes.

Comment: EXACTLY - there is a simple way to create this trace. For a couple of dozens cubes you do not need a general solution.

Comment: @Moti: Don't forget that for rendering, you do also need the fractional coordinates on each face where the ray intersects the plane.  And this has to be fast enough to be done millions of times per second, to be efficient.  And rays intersecting a plane may or may not be stopped by that plane depending on those fractional coordinates.

Comment: This is not really a rendering problem. Mathematically you could calculate easily numerous intersection points and than organize them with a simple calculation. Assuming a 1G processor with 1000 cycles per block will allow finding the ray through 1000000 blocks.

Comment: Just, I don't understand the fractional part. Why ty became 1.667 ? How do you find those values ? Other parts are fine, but this begin disturbs me

Comment: @Elikill58:  Starting $y$ coordinate of the ray is $s_y = 4.5$, with the distance along the ray between consecutive intersections of $y$ plane $T_y = 7/3 \approx 2.333$, with direction towards negative $y$ ($d_y \lt 0$).  This means that the distance from the starting $y$ coordinate to the very first intersection of an integer $y$ plane is the fractional part of the starting $y$ coordinate ($0.5$) of the inter-y-plane distance $2.333$, i.e. $t_y \approx 0.5 × 2.333 \approx 1.667$.  If the starting $y$ coordinate were say $8.1$, the $t_y \approx 0.1 × 2.333 \approx 0.233$.

Comment: @Elikill58: Now, if $d_y \gt 0$, and starting $y$ coordinate were say $3.6$, then $t_y \approx (1 - 0.6) × 2.333 = 0.4 × 2.333 \approx 0.933$.  In other words, for negative directions, we multiply the fractional part of the starting coordinate with the plane intersection distance, to get the very first intersection distance.  For positive directions, we subtract the fractional part of the starting coordinate from $1$, and multiply the result with the plane intersection distance.

Comment: @Elikill58: The reason for this is simple: to travel one coordinate unit along the $y$ axis, we need to travel $T_y$ along the ray.  If we need to travel a fraction of an coordinate unit, say $\lambda$, then we need to travel $\lambda T_y$ along the ray.  For the initial intersections, we get that fraction $\lambda$ directly from the fractional part (right of the decimal point, often called "decimal part") of the starting coordinate if traveling towards negative coordinates; and subtracting that from $1$ if traveling towards positive coordinates.  Draw a grid, and experiment, to see.

Comment: My, uh, 'friend', Glärbo has described this more in depth in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4081621/977814), including example Python code (that rasterizes a simple voxel scene).